# React Native not finding a file with a .ios or .android extension, because it's only looking for .native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

```
None of these files exist:
  * ../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.cjs|.cjs|.native.native|.native|.native.json|.json)
  * ../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.cjs|.cjs|.native.native|.native|.native.json|.json)
  12 |
  13 | // Components
> 14 | import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
```

This is happening after migrating to a monorepo and switching back to a managed Expo workflow.

I'm guessing it may have something to do with my metro config, so I'll include that too:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

const projectRoot = __dirname;
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot];
config.resolver = {
  ...config.resolver,
  nodeModulesPath: [
    path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
    path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules'),
  ],
  sourceExts: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
};

config.transformer = {
  getTransformOptions: async () => ({
    transform: {
      experimentalImportSupport: false,
      inlineRequires: true,
    },
  }),
  minifierPath: require.resolve('metro-minify-esbuild'),
  minifierConfig: {},
};

module.exports = config;
```

I am on an older version of RN/Expo for the migration (plan to update after) - Expo 44/RN 64.3, so it may be related to that in some way, though I doubt it.

I'm not really seeing much on the web about what might cause something like this - has anyone seen an issue like this, and how did they go about solving it?

Answer (score 0):

if you have this error please try this
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36794#issuecomment-1500880284

Workarounds

The symbolication error hides a separate, underlying error - if you switch to an older iOS version you should see the real error (or warning) that triggered symbolication in the first place. Address that, and it should go away on 16.4 too.

Develop on an older version of iOS (new Xcode is fine). This issue only affects the development process (and any production error reporting) - production users on 16.4 shouldn't experience any issue.
Switch to Hermes - I appreciate that isn't a trivial change.
Use Metro's server.rewriteRequestUrl to "guess" the query string if it seems to be missing. Note that there are other parameters besides platform that affect the bundle output, you'll need to make sure these are right for your setup - details below have the defaults for a react-native init project.

Using server.rewriteRequestUrl in metro.config.js

```
// metro.config.js
module.exports = {
  server: {
    rewriteRequestUrl: (url) => {
      if (!url.endsWith('.bundle')) {
        return url;
      }
      // https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36794
      // JavaScriptCore strips query strings, so try to re-add them with a best guess.
      return url + '?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true';
    }, // ...
  }, // ...
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35655763)